# mod rewrite causing error with pretty urls in SMF forum

Tags: mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I installed a mod (pretty urls) to rewrite the urls of this SMF forum and it works for all the boards except this one:

[http://mmaturf.com/forum/genghis-con's-turf/](http://mmaturf.com/forum/genghis-con%27s-turf/)

I believe it has to do with apostrophe, but my mod rewrite skills are negligible.

The rule that was created looks like this:

```
# Rules for: boards
RewriteRule ^([-_!~*'()$a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;board=$1.0 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([-_!~*'()$a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([0-9]*)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;board=$1.$2 [L,QSA]
```

Any assistance would be appreciated!

Comment: the previous page leading to this one can be found here:
<a href="http://mmaturf.com/forum/highlight-tv-turf/">http://mmaturf.com/forum/highlight-tv-turf/</a>

Comment: Where do you use those rules? In the .htaccess file in `/forum/`?

Comment: Yes, the .htaccess fule in /forum/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is still unanswered.

The apostrophe in the Regexp means the expression can contain the apostrophe symbol.

The problem lies in the MOD itself. Navigate to Subs-PrettyUrl.php in the Sources of SMF and find.

'' => array ('?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '«', '»', ':', '&', '+', '@', '%', '^', '?', '#'),

The add any symbol you want the URL to ignore in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping the apostrophe in the rule, i.e.

```
RewriteRule ^([-_!~*\'()$a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;board=$1.0 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([-_!~*\'()$a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([0-9]*)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;board=$1.$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although it didn't seem to fix the problem!